# Can viewWillDisappear be called directly?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

Does anyone have an official reference for why methods such as 'viewWillDisappear' should not be called directly?  There are several existing posts on the subject but no official link, only opinions.

It does not make sense to do so as it is calling a method "out of cycle" from the lifetime management of a view.  They can be, and in many cases are, overridden of course.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html

The issue in question is for some code I encountered where 'viewWillDisappear' is being called from some method.  It is really the content of the 'viewWillDisappear' method that is needed to be called.

Example:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // The following two methods are the ones that need to be called below
    [self someMethod];
    [self anotherMethod];
}

- (void)delegateMethod
{
    [self viewWillDisappear:YES];
    // Do some other work
    // View is moved off-screen, not deallocated, and therefore, does not "disappear"
}
```

Instinctively it appears wrong to call any of the view hierarchy methods directly (e.g. viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear).  If you tell 'self' and the 'super' view that viewWillDisappear it may do something in the framework that could cause problems later on.  I think these methods should be called by the framework only.  However, this is my opinion and not an official source.  The header files don't seem to provide anything about this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary if you remove view properly. Can you add a code where you are adding and removing this view from parent view ? Make sure you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

especially  "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" part

Comment: The code is unfortunately too lengthy to post (I didn't write it). It is added essentially to the navigation controller. The view is never removed.  It slides in/out as needed.

Comment: FYI `[self viewWillDisappear];` should be `[self viewWillDisappear:YES];` or `[self viewWillDisappear:NO];` ... But it doesn't make sense to use `viewWillDisappear` in that way anyway...

Answer (score 3):

There is no technical reason you can't.

But you shouldn't.

It's bad coding practice and you might confuse the reader or, worse, make him/her not trust you.

Good coding practice would be the following:

```
- (void)delegateMethod
{
  [self doCommonWork];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [self doCommonWork];
}

- (void)doCommonWork 
{
  // …
}
```

Comment: I agree that it is bad coding practice, and for those reasons.  The code stood out pretty quickly to me.  I don't know if we can be certain of no side-effects as I don't know what "[super viewWillDisappear:animated];" is actually doing.